# Is it possible to convert an OCX file to a TLB file?

Tags: c++builder, ocx

I'm trying to automate a build, but the instructions require openning an OCX in Borland C++ Builder and saving it as a TLB.  How can I reproduce this process through the command line?

Answer (score 1):

With Delphi/C++Builder 2009, you can use the TLIBIMP and GENTLB command line tools:

1. 1. `tlibimp -I comdlg32.ocx -Ftcomdlg32`
   This will generate a comdlg32.ridl file (RIDL is a variant of Microsoft's IDL).
2. 2. `gentlb comdlg32.ridl`
   This generates the comdlg32.tlb file.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall, you can use tlbimport. I will admit it's been a long time, and tlbimport may have been part of the VC++ redist.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the nicest solution, but it's the only one I can find that works automatically. I downloaded a free program called AutoHotkey to emulate the keystrokes for openning the ocx file in BCB5, checking off the 'Can Create' checkbox under the Flags tab and saving the file as a tlb.  It helps get through the annoying translation warning as well!